# sqllite db saved count is wrong

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I am using SugarORM for Sqllite db and the data in this db saved every 10 minutes from server which is done by using the service. Now, while observing the data saved in the logcat count of data saved in this DB is showing wrong. Logcat shows like below

> I/Sugar: mobstat saved : 255322 
>  I/Sugar: mobstat saved : 255323 
>   
>  I/Sugar: mobstat saved : 255117 
>  I/Sugar: mobstat saved :
>   255118

After it reaching the 323 it is again showing for 117 and so on. What is wrong here.

```
private void parseJSONresponse(String s)
{
   try
      {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
        {
          JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
          musers.add(new mobstat(e.getString("name"), e.getString("status"),e.getLong("time")));
          SugarRecord.saveInTx(musers);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Mobstat sqllite table:

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.orm.dsl.Unique;

class mobstat extends SugarRecord {

    @Unique
    String name;
    String status;
    long stime;

    public mobstat(){  }

    mobstat(String name, String status, long stime) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.stime = stime;
    }
}
```

mobstat is my sqllite db. this code is running every 10 seconds to update the new data. I am not doing any check whether data already exist or not, the Sugar ORM is overwrite the values which is already exist. Is this the correct approach? Please help.

Comment: Check your Table Has any primary key then , If the value for that column are same then it must be replace OR there may any data value is null that's why data could not be stored into Table .

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if Sugar really overwrites your data or is it something that you assume based on the logs of Sugar?

Every time you call the next line:

```
SugarRecord.saveInTx(musers);
```

You save the whole List of `musers` again.

The Logs you show us are the logs of `Sugar`, that is something you should not  worry about or look at. I think your code doesn't override the existing values in the database since you only save objects to `Sugar`.